# PHP statement between quotes

Tags: php, quotes

How can I put a php statement between quotes, inside php?

I want to call str_replace(), and the first argument is a string that is a PHP statement, that I want to replace).

The string is: `<?php echo $_GET['number'];?>`

Now, how do I put that into quotes? Is it possible? I just want that to be treated as a string.

Thank you!

Comment: `$_GET['number']` **is a string**. Just work with it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this all you're trying to do?

```
echo '<?php echo $_GET["number"];?>';
```

I think we're a little confused.

Comment: Yes that's all :) I guess I am too tired, too much coding today, time to sleep for me. Thanks everyone :)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to output that exact text to an html page just do

```
<?php
echo htmlentities('<?php echo $_GET["number"];?>');
```

I may have misunderstood what you wanted though...

Comment: You need to escape `$` sign as long as the string is within `"`

Comment: @zerkms, thanks. Actually think I beat you to it on the edit... ;)

Comment: hmmm not working... What I want to accomplish is to replace certain texts in a PHP file, using str_replace... One of the strings that I want to replace is <?php echo $_GET["number"];?> ... So I am trying to put that, as a string, inside the str_replace first argument... But not sure how to do it, your solution gives me the html tags, which is not good, I need all the exact symbols.

Comment: You want to actually alter the source code for a specific file? Like have file a.php alter file b.php ?

Comment: @Frankie: if OP wanted to output exactly `<?php echo $_GET['number'];?>` string - then your answer is wrong, because of double-quotes around the key name ;-P

Comment: @zerkms I didn't even though possible that Aaron was asking how to print the string without even trying first... well... and let him find out about the `\`" all by himself... :)